# How to get to Auschwitz-Birkenau from Wroclaw?

Tags: planning, public-transport, poland, auschwitz, krakow

I would like to know how to get to Auschwitz from Wrocław without going first to Kraków by public transport? The idea is to get up early in Wrocław, visit Auschwitz and go to Kraków to sleep.

One option is to go to Katowice, but I don't know if that's possible. As far as I know Wrocław to Katowice is 3 hours by train, then I have to go to take a train or bus to Auschwitz (1 hour) and should reserve 4 hours for the visit. Finally a bus could take me to Kraków but the problem is that (according to the Lonely Planet) the last one departs at 6pm.

Do you see this planning viable? Or do you know another less stressing/direct way to get Auschwitz?

Comment: Did you do this trip? Did it work out?

Comment: More or less: we take a train from Wroclaw to Oświęcim (train change at Trzebinia) and then a taxi to Birkenau (9 PLN). After the visit, we try to find a bus to go to Krakow but cannot find. Finally we take a train from Oświęcim to Trzebinia and from here another one to Kraków (9 PLN, 3 hours). You can check my blog if you read Spanish or use a translator: http://apeadero.es/2012/06/auschwitz/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go by train from Wrocław to Oświęcim (Auschwitz) and then from Oświęcim to Kraków. The last train from Oświęcim to Kraków is at 20h54. You can check the train times and fares [here](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/?q=en/node/143).

I think that a less stressing way is to go to Kraków first and visit Oświęcim on a day trip from there. Alternatively, if you do not want to go to Kraków first, you could consider to spend the night in Oświęcim. This could be the night before or after the visit.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't imagine that Oświęcim could be reached directly from Wroclaw

Comment: Note that the train from Wrocław to Oświęcim is not direct. You have to change trains, at leadt once.

Comment: Opss, that's true, but it's still better than stopping at Katowice, Thanks! :)